# Why is the 110th disbanded?

Tags: plot-explanation, reacher

In S2E7, a flashback shows Reacher telling his 110th that they are going to make arrests in Operation Kite. A team member reminds him that they were given orders not to pursue this, and that the operation in general hat been 'fubared', i.e. sabotaged at every turn. Reacher then goes into a speech about how they are probably nerfing their carreers with this move, but it's worth it anyhow.

They make the arrest and immediately the 110th is disbanded by Reacher's commanding officer Fields (who in turn bemoans a dressing down by *his* commanding officer, a Colonel). Nobody argues, nobody seems surprised about who does the axing. The last time Fields was seen was in another flashback, where he came over as pretty beloved by the team, and a generally nice guy.

Did i miss something about this character's arch? The operation was a resounding success, yet it is somehow taken as a given that this precludes the 110th from further existing as a unit, and that the guy who had the idea for the super-sleuth-110th himself does the axing, without any hesitation or remorse. What gives.

I can see how a secret cabal of shadowy government&military types could be hindering the investigation, even to such a visible degree that the (not-part-of-the-conspiracy) higher-ups tell Reacher to not further rock the boat (Perhaps on the mistaken assumption that REacher is chasing shadows). But after the investigation triumphantly manages to secure a ton of drugs and (i assume) some alive perps to interrogate, i cannot conceive how that would end as it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the squad isn't disbanded, there's no possible vengeance as in the season. But that's not the only reason: it has to be coherent with military practices.

> 1. A team member reminds him that they were given **orders not to pursue this**.
> 2. A speech about how they are probably **nerfing their carreers with this move**.
> 3. They make the arrest and **the 110th is disbanded** by commanding officer.

It doesn't matter if they succeeded or not, if there's a conspiracy or not, it's insubordination<sup>1</sup> and the squad falls under [Article 92 - Failure to obey an order](https://www.mcmilitarylaw.com/articles-of-ucmj/article-92-failure-to-obey-an-order/):

> Article 92 defines disobeying a direct order as three types of offenses - violations or failures to obey lawful general orders or regulations, failures to obey other lawful orders, and dereliction of duty. Article 92 charges are common in many prosecutions.

More precisely,

> FAILURE TO OBEY OTHER LAWFUL ORDER:
>
> That a member of the armed forces issued a certain lawful order;
>
> That the accused had knowledge of the order; and
>
> That the accused had a duty to obey the order; and
>
> That the accused failed to obey the order.

You say that **nobody argues, nobody seems surprised about who does the axing.** Because they knew that heads would roll, and that they would be axed, not matter what. Either the "conspirators" win, and they're down, or they are charged with disobeying an order and they're down. You can't disobey (what can be seen as) a lawful direct order and expect no consequences. That would be a wrong signal to others in the forces ("*Hey guys! Do what you want and f-- the orders!*"). Having been in the Army (not the US), I can tell you it first goes up the ladder (chain of command), then the shit hits the fan, and it goes back down the ladder. It's almost the same everywhere around the world in military environement.

[When can a soldier disobey an order ?](https://warontherocks.com/2017/07/when-can-a-soldier-disobey-an-order/)

[Uniform Code of Military Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Code_of_Military_Justice)

[Willfully Disobeying Superior Commissioned Officer](https://www.armfor.uscourts.gov/digest/IIIA14.htm) (even if this can be considered less of an offence than Reacher's, it's still the case...)

> Beyond establishing the unit cohesion of the 110th survivors, the extended flashback serves to underscore the fact that they are not heroes. They do heroic things and seem to only kill the baddies who really deserve it. They are courageous in the heat of battle and **know the cost of defying orders they felt were morally wrong**. They pursue the villains, fighting and surviving like superheroes, Reacher especially. However, they are more like the Punisher than Batman. [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/reacher-season-2-episode-7-review/)

---

<sup>1. Insubordination is when a service member willfully disobeys the lawful orders of a superior officer. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insubordination)</sup>

Comment: So the orders that clearly covered for a criminal conspiracy would be recorded? Implicating the order-givers? And why is Fields so enraged towards them? He got a dressing-down by his superior, but still has his command intact, and now has to axe the people he (seemed to) care for - why has he anger towards them?

Comment: No, the direct order is to make the arrest (one guy will go to jail, 4 on parole IIRC) in a way that will not involve higher ranked officers (keeping the sheets clean for the colonel craving the promotion for 20 years is just another excuse). So, *technically*, the order is to make the arrest, and it can be recorded. Off record, it says "*play soft*"